# How to implement stripe in my laravel platform where multiple companies can receive payments from customers?

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I have a laravel platform where there are multiple companies that provide different services to customers. I need to implement stripe so that the companies can receive their respective payments from customers directly using same stripe api key.

For that I have created an account in stripe and under that added some connections with different emails for the companies and took their own account id.

**So I want to know is my code correct or I have to add something more or correct something ? I am not sure if I have already implemented the code or not**

I have implemented my codes in controller like this :

```
public function stripePost(Request $request)
    {
        Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));

        Stripe\Charge::create(
            [
                "amount" => 100 * 100,
                "currency" => "AUD",
                "source" => $request->stripeToken,
                "description" => "This is test payment",
            ],
            ['stripe_account' => 'acct_1.......']
        );
        Session::flash('success', 'Payment Successful !');

        return back();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Standard connected account, Direct Charges should be used: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges

If you use Express/Custom connected account, Destination Charges should be used: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges

Both integration types will transfer funds to the connected account automatically after the payment is made successfully.

Charges API is legacy integration and no longer recommended. You should use Payment Intent integration alongside with Payment Element (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements) as suggested above.